# como tornar um campo obrigatório

Tags: c#, html5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Estou dando manutenção em uma pagina usando Asp.net MVC e utilizando do Kendo Asp.Net MVC e preciso tornar dois campos obrigatórios, porém não estou conseguindo

index.cshtml:

```
    <div class="col-lg-2 demo-section k-content" id="dayId">
        <label class="control-label">@Messages.TotalSwitching_Date - @Messages.TotalSwitching_Start</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("firstDay")
          .Events(e => e.Change("firstDayChange"))
          .Start(CalendarView.Month)
          .Depth(CalendarView.Month)
          .Format("MM dd yyyy")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 50%" })
          .Value(ViewBag.FirstDate)
          .Min(ViewBag.FirstDate)
          .Max(ViewBag.LastDate)
        )
        <label class="control-label">@Messages.TotalSwitching_Date - @Messages.TotalSwitching_End</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("lastDay")
          .Events(e => e.Change("lastDayChange"))
          .Start(CalendarView.Month)
          .Depth(CalendarView.Month)
          .Format("MM dd yyyy")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 50%" })
          .Max(ViewBag.LastDate)
          .Min(ViewBag.FirstDate)
        )
    </div>
```

Comment: Basta definir na model que o atributo não pode ser nulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em seu model pode definir seu atributo como Required, basta apenas inserir a TAG [Require] e importar DataAnnotations.

Exemplo: `[Required]
        public string Nome { get; set; }`